# Scala Play "dist" command creates zip archive with 2 entries with identical file names

Tags: scala, maven, playframework, sbt, stanford-nlp

Our Play Scala project includes the Stanford NLP package as a dependency, declared as follows in our Build.scala file:

```
val coreNlp  = "edu.stanford.nlp"  % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.2.0"
```

The dependency is resolved on **[Maven](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)** and results in the download of two distinct jar files:

```
stanford-corenlp-3.2.0.jar 
stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-models.jar
```

as shown when searching **[Maven](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C304695436)**.

So far, so good: our Play app works properly.

But when we package the app using one of the commands below:

```
play dist
sbt dist
```

both jar files end up with the same exact name,

```
edu.stanford.nlp.stanford-corenlp-3.2.0.jar
```

in the resulting .zip archive artifact, as shown by running the following command on the .zip file:

```
unzip -lv generated-dist.zip
```

Subsequently, when the .zip is later inflated to deploy the app, only one of the two jar files survives, and we're unable to run the app thus deployed, since one of the two jars ends up missing.

Is there a workaround, e.g. a different way to declare the dependency, to avoid name collision when dist is executed?

Comment: What are the models??

Comment: If there's anything we should change in the Maven packaging, let us know, but I don't know anything about Play or Cloudbees....

Comment: Solved. 
Had to upgrade to a more recent version of the SBT Native Packager, by specifying the following in plugins.sbt:

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.6.4")

and further refined the dependency declaration in Build.scala to:
val coreNlp             = "edu.stanford.nlp"   % "stanford-corenlp"     % "3.2.0" classifier("") classifier("models")